# DB Transaction happening when adding object in array into an Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I everybody!

I have a little problem :

Let's define thoses objects

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bs

  def add_some_b(b)
     do_some_stuff_with_b(b)
     bs << b
  end
end
class B < AR
   def some_stuff
   end
end
```

When I call this :

```
some_a_variable.new
some_a_variable.add_some_b(some_b)
```

I have a transaction opened and immediately closes, nothing happening inside:

[2011-09-01 18:58:49][DEBUG]   SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
[2011-09-01 18:58:49][DEBUG]   SQL (0.1ms)  COMMIT

Why? How can I avoid this?

Comment: do you want to save these to the database?

Comment: not exactly when I add the B AR through the "<<" method, but after.

Comment: did u call `some_a_variable.save` after calling `some_a_variable.add_some_b(some_b)`?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the other side of your has_many relationship:

```
class B < AR
  belongs_to :a

   def some_stuff
   end
end
```